# Как вывести имена столбцов из бд циклом?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть база даных с соответсвующими столбцами . Нужно циклом вывести все их названия . Как это сделать ?

Comment: Обязательно циклом?

Comment: можно по-другому . Суть в том  , что есть таблица и надо  <th> заполнить названиями столбцов

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll();
$keys = array_keys($data[0]);

foreach ($keys as $title) echo "<th>$title</th>";
foreach ($data as $row) // выводим строки с данными
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: что такое TABLE_SCHEMA?